# Jsch won't accept RSA SSH-2 private key from PuttyGen / Export OpenSSH key

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I have created an RSA 2048 key pair with PuttyGen, and exported the private key as OpenSSH key ( with and without force new file format ).

When trying to open an SFTP connection with Jsch I get an error message

> Auth cancel

I have tested the connection with Filezilla and it works fine.

I have tried to convert the private key file to different formats with openssl.exe, but none of those conversions worked either.

I have tried different linefeeds, \n and \r\n.

I'm running Windows 7 and Talend Data Integration -tool.

Comment: Why are you using SSH-1 in 2017? You're a decade out of date.

Comment: Oh sorry, they key is actually RSA SSH-2 but the file format is older OpenSSH, not the newer one. Edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I managed to make the correct keyfile, but I had changed the username to a wrong one. Both of these errors were "Auth cancel".